# PGSQL Error Code 42703 column does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I have a database in postgreSQL. I want to read some data from there, but I get an error (`column anganridref does not exist`) when I execute my command.

Here is my NpgsqlCommand:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from angebot,angebotstatus,anrede where anrid=anganridref and anstaid=anganstaidref";
```

and my 3 tables

[image: http://img4.fotos-hochladen.net/uploads/unbenanntg4059ucm6j.png]

the names of my columns are rights. So I don't understand why that error comes. Someone can explain me why it does crash? Its not the problem of large and lowercase.

Comment: Connect to the database using psql, and do "\d table_name" for all of the tables. And then show us the output. Not sure what generated the graph above and if it can be trusted when it comes to details of table column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not prefixing your column names in the where clause:

```
select * 
from angebot,
     angebotstatus,
     anrede 
where anrid = anganridref   <-- missing tablenames for the columns
  and anstaid = anganstaidre
```

It's also recommended to use an explicit `JOIN` instead of the old SQL 89 implicit join syntax:

```
select * 
from angebot 
   join angebotstatus on angebot.aaaa = angebotstatus.bbbb
   join anrede on angebot.aaaa = anrede.bbbb
```